# PrimeFaces locales does not work well when i put PrimeFaces.locales setting in a separate javascript file

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

I have the following issue. When i put PrimeFaces.locales settings (i mean https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/wiki/PrimeFacesLocales) in the .xhtml file my calendar is translated correctly in the language i want. I need Date picker in many places so i it is better to be in separate file. But when i create a new .js file for the  PrimeFaces.locales settings and include it in the .xhtml file with the command:

```
<h:outputScript library="js" name="calendar.js" />
```

The name of months, days are not readable. May be some encoding issue... Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the problem was with the encoding. The .xhtml file was with Encoding UTF-8 without BOM, but that is why when the code for changing locale was in .xhtml file, it looks ok. After i converted .js file from ANSI to UTF-8 encoding, the months and days are readable.